# fs library : Error when use it

Tags: node.js

I use `fs` library for reading file from system. I don't know I use this library and meet error.

1. I'm using PhpStorm. at line : `fs.readFile()` : there's a line under that, that notice me : unresolved function or method readFile(). It means IDE doesn't figure out where is this function. Nevertheless, I have checked `fs.js` and I see no problem.
2. I receive this error when running:

> events.js:72
>           throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>                 ^ Error: listen EADDRINUSE
>       at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
>       at Server._listen2 (net.js:1039:14)
>       at listen (net.js:1061:10)
>       at Server.listen (net.js:1127:5)
>       at Object. (/home/hqt/PhpstormProjects/NodeApp/sample/AsynchronouslyReading.js:21:4)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)

Here is my code :

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

// create http server
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile('helloworld.js', 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'content-type' : 'text/plain'});
        if (err) res.write('could not find or open file');
        else res.write(data);

        // ending
        res.end();
    });
}).listen(8124, function() {console.log('server is running at 8124');});

console.log('server is runnint at 8124 port');
```

Please help me figure out why. I'm using Ubuntu machine for development.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because something else is already listening on port 8124. On Linux, you can use something like `netstat -tanp | grep LISTEN | grep 8124` to see what.

Comment: Ah. thanks :) It's true. But after I run this file, I press Control + Z to stop server. (and I have checked again, for example : localhost:8124, cannot, it means my server has stopped). But the port is still in used. How can I stop node server properly from console ? Thanks :)

Comment: @hqt, with Control + C. Control + Z only pauses the process, doesn't stop it (you can bring it back to the foreground with `fg`).

Comment: ah. sooo thanks :D I'm a new comer at linux world, i press control + Z, and it's terminated. (and I don't know anything behind). thank you so much for helping me :D